# How to make join query in Hibernate using Spring MVC

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two tables. : Airport, FlightSchedule.

They have one-two-many relation each other.

Below is the hibernate data file.

Airport.java :

```
public class Airport implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer airportId;
    private String airportName;
    private String airportCountry;
    private String airportCity;
    private Set<FlightSchedule> depFlightSchedule = new HashSet<FlightSchedule>(0);
    private Set<FlightSchedule> arrFlightSchedule = new HashSet<FlightSchedule>(0);

}
```

FlightSchedule.java :

```
public class FlightSchedule implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer flightscheduleId;
    private Date depDay;
    private Date depTime;
    private Date arrDay;
    private Date arrTime;
    private Double flightTime;
    private Integer price;
    private Set<BoardingPass> boardingPasses = new HashSet<BoardingPass>(0);

    private Airplane airplane;
    private Airport depAirport;
    private Airport arrAirport;

}
```

In FlightSchedule, they must have two relations with Airport. Because they need 'departure airport information' and 'arrival airport information'.

So, if I get two string input (departure airport name, arrival airport name), I want to make join table (FlightSchedule X Airport) and print all the information.

For example, If I have two input 'Korea' and 'Austrailia', then I want to print information about departure Korea, arrival Austrailia.

Like this! :

departureDate | departureAirport | arrivalDate | arrivalAirport

2017-12-01 | Incheon International Airport | 2017-12-10 | Sydney International Airport

-- departure Date, arrival Date come from 'FlightSchedule' table.

-- departureAirport name, arrivalAirport name come from 'Airport' table.

Actually, I tried this on mysql:

SELECT * FROM flight_schedule as f

inner join airport

on f.dep_airport_id=(select id from airport where airport.country='korea')

and f.arr_airport_id=(select id from airport where airport.country='Austrailia')

but it wasn't what I want.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you want to perform a join with airport with the condition where airport has two different values at the same time, so this is impossible. You have to make two joins with this table for each condition.

```
SELECT * FROM flight_schedule as f

inner join airport a1

on f.dep_airport_id=(select id from airport where a1.country='korea')

inner join airport a2

on f.arr_airport_id=(select id from airport where a2.country='Austrailia')
```